# Flex easing - show / hide window?

Tags: apache-flex, easing

Im working on a display that starts with a centered logo and menu. When one of the menu items is clicked I move the logo and menu to the left side and show a datagrid on the right. Is there a way to use an easing function to make this change look better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes! To illustrate it I've created the following sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application minHeight="600" minWidth="955" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Bounce id="easer1" />
        <s:Elastic id="easer2" />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="intro" />
        <s:State name="main" />
    </s:states>
    <s:transitions>
        <s:Transition fromState="intro" toState="main">
            <s:Sequence>
                <s:Move disableLayout="true" easer="{easer2}" target="{menuGroup}" />
                <s:SetAction property="verticalCenter" target="{menuGroup}" value="{NaN}" />
                <s:SetAction property="horizontalCenter" target="{menuGroup}" value="{NaN}" />
                <s:AddAction target="{dg}" />
                <s:Fade easer="{easer1}" target="{dg}" />
            </s:Sequence>
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>
    <s:VGroup horizontalCenter.intro="0" id="menuGroup" left.main="10" top.main="10" verticalCenter.intro="0">
        <s:Label text="Logo is here" />
        <s:Button click="currentState = 'main'" label="Click Me!" />
        <s:Button click="currentState = 'main'" label="Click Me!" />
    </s:VGroup>
    <mx:DataGrid bottom="10" id="dg" includeIn="main" left="{menuGroup.width + 20}" right="10" top="10">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="First" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Second" />
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</s:Application>
```